# Access to sending invitation denied in linked from android using linkedin-j-android.jar

Tags: linkedin-api

I am using linked-in integration using custom-linkedin-j-android.jar for login and invitation by Id .
It was working fine before the linked-in policy and Api modification but now it always showing below exception .

com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.LinkedInApiClientException: Access to sending invitation denied.

Please give your suggestion for same.